# Disable Form row selection when row contains a Button

Tags: swift, forms, swiftui

I have a `Form` and I added a `Button` to a row but that made the whole row selectable which is not what I intended. I want the eye button to be tappable while removing row selection.

[image]

The upper row has no buttons so it's not selectable while the second one is because there is this eye button.

Tried adding a `.allowsHitTesting(false)` and an empty `.onTapGesture {}` modifier but the former does nothing while the second also disables the eye button.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that having a `Button` embed in a `Form` row enables row selection no matter the modifiers you use or how you embed the button (`ZStack`s, etc.).

The only solution was to not use buttons at all and use a regular `Image` instead with a `. onTapGesture`  modifier:

```
Image(systemName: self.secure ? "eye" : "eye.fill")
    .foregroundColor(self.secure ? .secondary : Color("appTint"))
    .onTapGesture { self.secure.toggle() }
```

Comment: The same applies to `Picker`, enables the entire row.

Answer (score 12):

You should set the `buttonStyle` to `PlainButtonStyle()`

```
Button(action {
    //Your Action
}) {
    //Your Content
}.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```